# Making random value in a loop stay that value

Tags: java, text

I'm creating a dungeon game. I want to have the chance of the player to be mutated and cause health loss over time. My problem is when the sequence is looped and the battle phase ended the mutation is re-randomized again. Meaning that if I get mutated and get inflicted with damage and the enemy is still alive it re does the "while" statement and randomize a value for mutation again.

```
if(input.equals("1")) {
    int damageDealt = rand.nextInt(attackDamage);
    int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyAttackDamage);
    int taken = rand.nextInt(mutation); //variable to see if a mutation occurs. Integer for mutation is 100.
    if (taken < 10) { 
// How do I tell the program to keep the number for taken?
// it will just re-loop and find a new rand.nextInt(mutation);
        enemyHealth -= damageDealt; //damage taken for enemy
        health -= damageTaken; //damage taken for player
        health -= rand.nextInt(maxMutationDamage); //damage taken from mutation. maxMutationDamage is 15
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You hit the " + enemy + " for " + damageDealt + " damage." + "\nYou receieved " + damageTaken + " damage." + "\nyour mutation did " + taken + " damage.");
    }
    else { 
        // I added this so that if the mutation didn't occur
        // the calculations for the fight still renders.
        enemyHealth -= damageDealt;
        health -= damageTaken;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You hit the " + enemy + " for " + damageDealt + " damage." + "\nYou receieved " + damageTaken + " damage.");
    }
    if(health < 1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you have taken to much damage!");
        break;
    }
}
else if (input.equals("2")) {
    if(numBandages > 0) {
        health += bandagesHealAmount;
        numBandages --;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You bandaged yourself for " + bandagesHealAmount + "."
                +"\nYou now have " + health + " HP."
                +"\nYou have " + numBandages + " bandages left.");
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have no bandages in inventory to heal!");
    }
}
else if (input.equals("3")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You ran away from the " + enemy + "!");
    continue GAME; //it resets the sequence of the dungeon to a new fight
}
```

also if you guys can help, how can I make it that even if the player runs away and doesn't heal he still get's wounded by mutation?

Mutation only stops when healing is done.

Comment: So when do you want to assign a new random value to taken? Obviously not every time the actions for input "1" are executed - but when?

Comment: Where is the while loop ?

Comment: the while loop is just above the if statement. I can add it in if you guys need that too. @laune, I'm trying to make it so that if they input 1 there is a chance for mutation. When that happens I want the taken value to stay true so that the if (taken < 10) will always happen. Though it will stop when we heal. But still stay true if we ran away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code showing how to set and keep a state variable. Not sure when to return to initial state.

```
int taken = -1;
while(...){ // continue game
    switch(input){
    case "1":
        if( taken == -1 ) taken = rand.nextInt(mutation);
        if(taken < 10 ){
            ...
        }
        ...
        break;
    case "2":
        ...
        // Does healing happen here?
        taken = -1; // return to initial state
        break;
    case "3":
        ...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would I put this? I'm still new to the concept of cases & switch.

Comment: The switch is meant to replace your if cascade. You'll have to fill in the gaps (...), mainly by copying the code from there.